# Converting a program that was set to use MyISAM to INNODB instead

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I have a database program that was written a few years back using MYISAM tables in a MYSQL database.  It is a pretty simple structure but I wasn't the one who set it up.

All the current releases of MYSQL are all set for INNODB and I just wondered how hard it would be to convert the current application from MYISAM to INNODB or is this something better handled by starting all over.

Considering I am not a database expert :)  Whatever way is the easiest.
I have found most if not all the declaratives in the modules that state for the program to use MyIsam and it sure would be nice if I could just change the necessary parts to restate that as INNODB and get it to work

Is there a physical obstruction to using innodb that would prevent the change fro MYISAM?
As I said these are very small databases maybe 25 fields in 100 records total maximum.

Thanks for any insight

Comment: I would have voted you up if I could have.  I have been scanning the setup and config files for every mention of ISAM and I was hoping I could just change them all to Innodb and get away with it

Answer (score 0):

There are several differences between MyISAM and InnoDB, nicely described in this discussion:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam

The only aspect which could prevent the use of InnoDB would be the full text search capabilities of MyISAM, which were introduced in InnoDB with version 5.6 of MySQL. So if your program does not make use of full text search, or if your MySQL version supports full text search with InnoDB, there is no real obstruction.

Given the small size of the database, and assuming a small traffic as well, I would not expect any substantial difference in terms of performances.